# How to match today's date in dataframe and send email messages

Tags: python, pandas, email, dataframe

I learning how to use pandas to deal with data and I find it pretty cool and fun. I am trying to build an automatic email system.

But now I am stocked with the following:
This question makes reference to one of my old questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45714149/convert-string-to-date-format-in-python-pandas-dataframe/45716364?noredirect=1#comment78465275_45716364).

This is how may data-set looks like:

[image]

I want to check if `datatime_from` is today and if it is true, take the email-address of that row and send an email message. I am using pandas as for the dataframe and my idea was to use smtplib for sending email messages, but I am open to use other libraries.

Here is my code until now:

```
import smtplib
import pandas 

def send_me_email():
  server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
  server.starttls()
  server.login('xxx@gmail.com', 'xxxxxxx')

  msg = "YOUR MESSAGE!"
  server.sendmail("YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS", "THE EMAIL ADDRESS TO SEND TO", msg)
  server.quit()

  msg = "YOUR MESSAGE!"
  server.sendmail("xxx@gmail.com", "xxx@gmail.com", msg)
  server.quit()

csv = pandas.read_csv('testfile.csv', delimiter=',')

#csv['datetime_from'].dtype

csv['datetime_from'] = pandas.to_datetime(csv['datetime_from'], errors='coerce')
#csv['datetime_from'].dtype

today_date = pandas.datetime.today().date()

csv2 = csv['datetime_from'].dt.date == today_date

csv['datetime_from'].where(csv).apply(send_me_email())
```

This is not working correctly, I cannot figure it out how to grab for all actual dates the corresponding email-addresses and send an email to those. The data file will be growing with new coming input every day.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the mask you get to index your data frame:

```
csv2 = csv[csv['datetime_from'].dt.date == today_date]
```

Furthermore, your `send_me_email` must take a parameter which `df.apply` passes to it:

```
def send_me_email(email):
    ...
```

This parameter is the E-Mail. Make sure you modify the body of your function to handle it accordingly.

You may now apply your function using `df.apply`. Do not *call* your function. You must pass it (without the `()`):

```
csv2['E-Mail'].apply(send_me_email)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. That's exactly my problem, how can I get to send the Email for all the affected rows. I understand the logic behind it but I am missing something in the function "send_me_email". I tried with "to_email = csv2.ix[:,7]" and "server.sendmail("andres@gmail.com", to_email, msg)"  in the send_me_mail function but it doesn't work.

Comment: Will appreciate any help on this, how can I create the function:
def send_me_email(email):
send = email.... so that i can pass the items from the dataframe to the function

Comment: @El_Patrón like I said, the function takes one parameter which is the addressee Email. All you need to do is write your code so it sends to that address.